# How to get metadata for email, letterhead, logo

Tags: apex, metadata-api, metadata

How can I get the metadata for email template, email signature letterhead, logo endpoints?

I'm trying to find out like the content in the email or email signature or the email template etc...

I haven't found online, any guidance on how to go forth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EmailTemplate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_emailtemplate.htm) and [BrandTemplate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_brandtemplate.htm) expose this information. You should be able to query them in Apex.

Here's some basic code that should include practically everything you want:

```
Map<Id, BrandTemplate> headers = new Map<Id, BrandTemplate>([
    SELECT Value
    FROM BrandTemplate
]);
EmailTemplate[] templates = [
    select body, folder.name,
    htmlvalue, markup, name,
    relatedentitytype, subject,
    templatestyle, templatetype,
    uitype
    from emailtemplate
];
```

Comment: Any idea about email signature?

Comment: @NickKahn The *user's* email signature? That's on the User object.

Comment: thanks and the last question where do i find `letterhead`

Comment: @NickKahn Letterhead is the BrandTemplate. I know it's not "obvious", but that's what it is: a template for your Brand.

Comment: never worked on this before, is there a way to access metadata for the `BrandTemplate` ? like I need to access `logo` and `color` for the letterhead etc..

Comment: @NickKahn It's all located in Value. You'll need to parse it somehow, probably via [Dom.Document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_xml_dom_document.htm). It's really just HTML.

Comment: FYI: logo you will find in `Document` object not in `BrandTemplate`

Comment: @NickKahn I kind of expected that, but it likely appears as a link in the BrandTemplate.Value, doesn't it?

Comment: yea i see the `<img link`